# GUI for server-client program

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am making a server-client application in c++. In this i am also using shared memory & file read-write operations. my program is completely ready & i now wants to make a gui for it. someone suggested me to go for QT4, but when i tried it, i found i have to re-write 80% of the code because QT has got its own classes & variable. i don't want to do it. i want suggestions from you on this regard. my requirements for gui are very simple i.e there will be a main form, which will have two text boxes in which all messages being sent & received by client & server should be shown. there should be another lineedit box, through which i can send the messages to the other end server. I don't know how to make this gui. someone suggested tcl/tk, other suggested me use php/swig. i am not sure how to go about this. my only requirement is that i want to make this simple gui with minimum of changes in my code. THANX

Comment: The best way to increase readability, save for not splitting the text into paragraphs, is to use lower case letters at the beginning of each sentence and replace all "and"s with an ampersand.

Comment: Which Operating System you intend to use ?

Comment: *i don't want to do it* - **I** don't want to answer people who are to lazy to provide an easily readable and understandable question. 

Every GUI framework has its own classes, functions and variables. The problem is likely with your code.

Comment: Sorry man, but we will need some more detailed information to help you out. And why would you need to rewrite 80% of your code in order to use Qt4 just for the GUI - this does not make sense.

Comment: i second humba/peterchen, imo Qt4 is compatible with standard C++ quite well e.g. QString has a .str() function to retrieve a std::string from it.. or QVector has a function fromStdVector to create a QVector from a std::vector...
The problems you experience are most likely with your code, not with Qt, and most likely you would experience the same problems with other GUI frameworks aswell, unless you fix those problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider making it a web app and using XHTML/CSS/JavaScript for the UI.  There is a C++ web framework called [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have any knowledge about what kind of adaption problems you have in your application, I have a hard time recommending any spesific toolkit, but if you go through [this list of toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) you should be able to find one that fits.

But in any case you should create a layer that separate the toolkit from your actual application so that the program and the tool kit are interchangeable entities. So my suggestion is to stick to QT and create such an layer. If you find it hard to write such a layer for your program, my thoughts are that you probably will have a hard time adapting to any of the toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

Each GUI framework will have it's own classes to which you have adapt your code. The grade of adaption may vary though.
Qt provides at lot more functionality than just the GUI, so maybe you can reuse some it in your application.
Maybe you can give some more details about what you want to do?